# Using $routeParams for custom views?

Tags: angularjs, routes

i was making a gallery using angular, i categorized images so when the gallery loads, each category is represented by an image, when user clicked on the image they would see the entire images of that gallery.

**for that i made an array so each image representing a category has a block that is an array and consist information of all images in that category.** and using that block for loading those images.

so i was trying to use $routeParams so i could make a url for each category to load data in that view, the representative image of categories are loading fine but i can't load the images of that category in the view.

my module code is:

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

            .when('/', {
                controller: 'contentsCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/contents.php'
            })

            .when('/news/', {
                controller: 'newsCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/news.php'
            })

            .when('/notes/', {
                controller: 'notesCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/notes.php'
            })

            .when('/records/', {
                controller: 'recordsCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/records.php'
            })

            .when('/gallery/', {
                controller: 'galleryCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/gallery.php'
            })

            .when('/gallery/:galleryID', {
                controller: 'imagesCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/images.php'
            })

            .when('/statute/', {
                controller: 'statuteCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/statute.php'
            })

            .when('/forms/', {
                controller: 'formsCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/forms.php'
            })

            .when('/about/', {
                controller: 'aboutCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/about.php'
            })

            .when('/contact/', {
                controller: 'ContactCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/contact.php'
            })

            .when('/post/', {
                controller: 'PostCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/post.php'
            })

            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});
```

and the code for the controller is:

```
(function () {
var imagesCtrl = function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

    $http.get("includes/gallery.php").success(function (response) {
        $scope.gallery = response.gallery;
    });

    var galleryID = $routeParams.galleryID;
    $scope.images = $scope.gallery[0];

    function init() {
        // Search gallery for the galleryID
        for (var i = 0, len = $scope.gallery.length; i < len; i++) {
            if ($scope.gallery[i].imageCategory == parseInt(galleryID)) {
                $scope.images = $scope.gallery[i].category;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    init();

};

imagesCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams'];

angular.module('myApp').controller('imagesCtrl', imagesCtrl);
}());
```

and this is the view:

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-lg-12">
    <h1 class="page-header">{{ galleryID }}</h1>
</div>
<a href="#/gallery/" class="btn btn-action pull left">Back to Gallery</a>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 thumb" ng-repeat="image in images">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="./uploads/images/{{ image.imageName}}" alt="" style="width:400px; height:160px;">
</div>
```

so anyone knows what is the problem? i would appreciate the help!

Comment: you mean you are not getting routeParams ?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling your init() function just after sending the $http request. It thus tries finding the gallery in $scope.gallery, but $scope.gallery is initialized long after, when the response to the $http request is available.

The code should be:

```
$http.get("includes/gallery.php").success(function (response) {
    $scope.gallery = response.gallery;
    init();
});

function init() {
    // Search gallery for the galleryID
    for (var i = 0, len = $scope.gallery.length; i < len; i++) {
        if ($scope.gallery[i].imageCategory == parseInt($routeParams.galleryID)) {
            $scope.images = $scope.gallery[i].category;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

That said, Why do you get all the galleries from the server for each page, supposed to render a single gallery. You should send the gallery ID to the server, and the server should respond with that category only, instead of always responding with all the galleries.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that on the view that it's suppose to load the controller, the controller returns error:
$scope.gallery is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use [`$router`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)`resolve`, the router will wait for these  promises to be resolved or one to be rejected before the controller is instantiated.

Route Setup:

```
.when('/gallery/', {
  controller: 'galleryCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'views/gallery.php'
  resolve: {
    gallery: ['$http', function($http) {      
        return $http
          .get('includes/gallery.php')
          .then(
            function success(response) {
              return response.data;
            },
            function error(reason) {
              return false;
            }
          );
      }
    ]
  } 
})
```

The controller should looks like this:

```
(function (angular) {
    var imagesCtrl = function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, gallery) {

        $scope.gallery = gallery;

        var galleryID = $routeParams.galleryID;
        $scope.images = $scope.gallery[0];

        function init() {
            // Search gallery for the galleryID
            for (var i = 0, len = $scope.gallery.length; i < len; i++) {
                if ($scope.gallery[i].imageCategory == parseInt(galleryID)) {
                    $scope.images = $scope.gallery[i].category;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        init();

    };

    imagesCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', 'gallery'];

    angular.module('myApp').controller('imagesCtrl', imagesCtrl);
}(angular));
```

Comment: TnX very much. I'll try it